# modify friendly_id gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id, ancestry

I want to be able in browsing bar see full path to some product. The path would look like this

```
www.mysite.com/categories/category_name/subcategory_name/product_name
```

At this moment I have just 
`www.mysite.com/categories/category_name`
It just provides with one level path, that I don't need.

To build these friendly links I used friendly_id. And full categorization function  I created using gem called Ancestry.

How can I modify friendly_id slug so that I can show the full path? I know how the friendly_id works, but I don't know how to change the way how slug is generated.

Some guys could just give me link or tip to search for. I can work it out, I just need idea.
I would be very greatfull :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a method for the gem to use, as in:

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :method_name, use: :slugged

def method_name

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for nested resouces.
If both models (category, subcategory) have slugs, nesting them in your `routes.rb` file should do the trick:

```
resources :categories do
  resources :subcategories
end
```